# Linked list in c add_before and add_after function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

While creating a linked list in order to add some data after an element and before an element i am using the following functions as i learned from the tutorial :

```
struct node *addafter(struct node *start,int data,int item)
{
    struct node *tmp,*p;
    p=start;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        if(p->info==item)
        {
            tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            tmp->info=data;
            tmp->link=p->link;
            p->link=tmp;
            return start;
        }
        p=p->link;
    }
    printf("Item Not Found:\n");
    return start;
}
struct node *addbefore(struct node *start,int data,int item)
{
    struct node *tmp,*p;
    if(item==start->info)
    {
        tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp->link=start->link;
        tmp->info=data;
        start->link=tmp;
        return start;
    }
    p=start;
    while(p->link!=NULL)
    {
        while(p->link->info==item)
        {
            tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            tmp->info=data;
            tmp->link=p->link;
            p->link=tmp;
            return start;
        }
        p=p->link;
    }
        printf("Item Not Found:\n");
    return start;
}
```

My doubt is in the addafter function why the stopping condition is p!=NULL and in case of addbefore function its p->link!=NULL?..Please can any one explain!

Comment: Drawing a graph about how it works by yourself will help you understanding.Simple explanation: In the `while` loop `addafter` will access `p->info`, so check `p` validation. In the `while` loop of `addbefore` will access `p->link`, so check `p->link` validation.

Comment: `while(p->link->info==item)` is wrong. Should be `if` not `while` because control returns (`return start;`) at the end of that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding a node to a single link list, you have to have a pointer to the node after which you add the node.

So if you want to add a node after the 3rd, you need a pointer to the 3rd node. 
And if you want to add a node before the 3rd, you need a pointer to the 2nd node.

So what pointer you need in before and after are different. Hence for the after case, your current pointer(`p` in your case) needs to point to the node where the item matches, whereas in the before case, your current pointer needs to point to the node before the one the item matches.

You can also rewrite the `addbefore` case with a `while(p!=NULL)` by maintaining a prev pointer.

```
struct node *addbefore(struct node *start,int data,int item)
{
    struct node *tmp,*p,*prv;
    if(item==start->info)
    {
        tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tmp->link=start->link;
        tmp->info=data;
        start->link=tmp;
        return start;
    }
    p = start->link;
    prv = start;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        if(p->info==item)
        {
            tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            tmp->info=data;
            tmp->link=p;
            prv->link=tmp;
            return start;
        }
        prv = p;
        p=p->link;

    }
        printf("Item Not Found:\n");
    return start;
}
```

Either way of writing the before code is fine.